# Variable = Executed script block with try/catch

Tags: powershell, try-catch, scriptblock

I am trying to look for the presence of a specific registry property and if present set a variable to the value. I will be doing an If/Then/ElseIf sequence, so I don't want to wrap the hole thing in a Try/Catch to address the fact that in PS5.1 `Get-ItemPropertyValue` doesn't support `-errorAction:silentlyContinue`, so I really want to set the value to the execution of a code block that includes the try/catch with an empty catch, something like this...

```
if ($value = @{try {Get-ItemPropertyValue "Registry::$nameKey" -name:AdskProductCode}catch{}}) {
```

I feel like it's possible and I am close and just missing some nuance. Or perhaps this is a stupid idea and there is a better approach?
They key reason for keeping the try/catch inside the if/then/else is because I will look for AdskProductCode and not finding that property I will look for AdskPackageCode, and in each case what I do with the value is different. If the try/catch wraps the iff then not finding AdskProductCode dumps me out completely and I never get to the else if looking for AdskPackageCode. Failing that there will be at least a final else, and maybe another else if, so simply looking for AdskPackageCode in the catch doesn't work. I could cascade the try/catch stuff, but good lord that's ugly.

Comment: don't do it that way. [*grin*] save the results of your 1st call, use an if to  decide if you want to make the 2nd call. you are making things FAR more difficult than needed ... save the results to $Vars and use those to make decisions.

Comment: Remove the `@{}` hashtable literal that surrounds the `try`/`catch` blocks

Comment: We'll, damnit, I thought I HAD tried if ($value = try {Get-ItemPropertyValue "Registry::$nameKey" -name:AdskProductCode}catch{}) { the first time, and it didn't work! Maybe the 30C heat today is cooking my brain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to address the fact that in PS5.1 Get-ItemPropertyValue doesn't support -errorAction:silentlyContinue

Indeed, **as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.1 / Windows PowerShell v5.1, `Get-ItemPropertyValue` unexpectedly reports a *statement-terminating* rather than a *non-terminating* error - and only the latter kind of error can be controlled with the common 
`-ErrorAction` parameter**.

This problematic behavior - restricted to the case where the registry *value* (as opposed to the containing *key*) doesn't exist -  has been reported in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5906).

---

It is only *terminating* errors that `try` / `catch` can control, and using an empty `catch` block for a *terminating* error is the equivalent of passing `-ErrorAction Ignore` to a cmdlet producing a *non-terminating* error.

Your only problem, as [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out, was that you mistakenly wrapped your `try` / `catch` statement in `@{ ... }` - a hashtable literal - which itself caused a statement-terminating error.

You may have been thinking of `$( ... )`, the subexpression operator, which would work in this case, but its use isn't necessary, so the following is enough:

```
if ($value = try { Get-ItemPropertyValue "Registry::$nameKey" -name:AdskProductCode } catch{}) { ...
```

**That is, you can *directly* use a `try` / `catch` statement as an *expression* and therefore assign it to a variable.**

---

Given that `Get-ItemPropertyValue`'s behavior may - and hopefully will - eventually be fixed, I suggest a different approach, however:

Use `Get-ItemProperty` instead, and access the value name of interest on the resulting object as a property:

```
if ($value = (Get-ItemProperty "Registry::$nameKey").AdskProductCode) { ...
```

Note:

- The general assumption is that key path `"Registry::$nameKey"` does exist (i.e., that it is only the registry *value* that may not exist); to ignore the non-existence of the key path too, use `-ErrorAction Ignore`.
- The above assumes that either no strict mode or at most strict mode version `1` is in effect.
- If, by contrast, `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher is in effect, don't use direct property access and pipe to `Select-Object -ErrorAction Ignore -ExpandProperty AdskProductCode` instead.